# How to read GPS data and accelerometer data in one activity

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-location

Is it possible the read GPS data and accelerometer data in one activity?
I Want to read the data and put in the text view.
I have already read the accelerometer data but the application crash when I add this code in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    valuesInitialization();
    sensorsInitialization();

}

private void valuesInitialization()
{
    Config.mContext = this;
    mInitialized = false;
    mLastAccelerometer[0] = INITVALUE;
    mLastAccelerometer[1] = INITVALUE;
    mLastAccelerometer[2] = INITVALUE;
    mLastGyroscope[0] = INITVALUE;
    mLastGyroscope[1] = INITVALUE;
    mLastGyroscope[2] = INITVALUE;
    mLastOrientation[0] = INITVALUE;
    mLastOrientation[1] = INITVALUE;
    mLastOrientation[2] = INITVALUE;
}

private void sensorsInitialization() 
{
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    mGyroscope = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

private void registListener() 
{
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
}

protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    registListener();
}

protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve the problem? Thanks in advance

The Error Log:[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the crash logs?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have add the error log picture and some codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must Implement a Location Listener in your class, as shown below

```
public class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    final String LOG_LABEL = "Location Listener>>";

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(util.TAG,LOG_LABEL+ "Location Changed");
        if (location != null)
        {
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.d(util.TAG,LOG_LABEL+ "Longitude:" + longitude);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Long::"+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lat::"+latitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(util.TAG,LOG_LABEL+ "Latitude:" + latitude);

            cleanUp();

        }
    }
```

And also define a location listener as shown below

```
private android.location.LocationListener locListener;
```

Then in order to get the listener get started , do

```
this.locListener = new LocationListener();
```

And once you get the long/lat values, do not forget to a clean up as shown below

```
cleanUp()
{
     // This needs to be done to stop getting the location data and save the
    // battery power.
    if (null != this.locListener && null != locationManager)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locListener);
        this.locListener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean implement in another class file? mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); will give me an error as it need the Context of MainActivity

Comment: No need, you can implement it in the same class file, as a sub class

Comment: does crash already. thanks. But I put a break point at if (location != null) and run as debug. it never go the break point

Comment: It takes dome time for the GPS to get the location details, depending on your location. And did you add permission in the manifest? like '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>'

Comment: In the cleanup function, if this.locListener = null; how can it be activated again?

Comment: If you want the location listener to be active, then do not call the cleanUp() method.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have added the permission for GPS in the Manifest.xml?

Comment: I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Ok, I thought it could be something like that

Answer (score 1):

At `registListener` (spelling incorrect) :

```
private void registListener() 
{
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
}
```

The error occurs because mLocationListener is null.

You should implement `LocationListener` in your own Activity, and in `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` pass `this` as the listener.

**EDIT**: If you implement `LocationListener` located at `android.location`, You would override these methods:

```
public void onLocationChanged (Location location);
public void onProviderEnabled (String provider);
public void onProviderDisabled (String provider);
public void onStatusChanged (String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
```

`onLocationChanged` is called when the user move distance that is equal to or above the distance specified in third parameter of `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates`, and when the time is elapsed more than the time specified in second parameter, in milliseconds. You can use the `location` object as whatever you want.

`onProviderEnabled` is called when one of the providers that provide GPS location is enabled. You can retrieve the type of provider (it could be `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` for GPS, or `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` for Wi-Fi or cellular location).

`onProviderDisabled` is similiar to `onProviderEnabled` but it is called when the provider is *disabled*.

and finally, all methods including `onStatusChanged` is documented on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

`Location` class is in package `android.location`, which provides current user location in altitude, bearing, speed, time, extras,  latitude, longitude, location provider and accuracy.

Comment: How to implement it, is it same as the sensor? I want to get the GPS data

Comment: @user2753594 Aren't you familiar with java listeners?